# call to member function find() on non-object in PHP?

Tags: php, dom, find, fatal-error

I am using `dom()` to parse the content from HTML. Basically inside tag `<img class="logo">`.

I am using `$this->dom->find('img[class=logo]')` to get the value.

But while doing this, sometimes I encounter an HTML which doesn't have the specified tag as above.

In that case, it is throwing an error - `Fatal error: call to member function find() on non-object`

I don't want that error to happen. Instead I want to skip if it is not able to find the specified tag.

I have also tried try-catch to skip errors but it doesn't work fine.

This is the code I have,

```
try {
    foreach ($this->dom->find('img[class=logo]') as $result) {
        //echo $result->src."\n";
        $li_img = $result->src;
    }
    if(!isset($li_img))
        return;
    else
        return $li_img;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    return;
}
```

I want to skip if `dom` is not able to find the tag. It is throwing error now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is `$this->dom` defined? That is what's causing your error.

Comment: And what dom interface is this `SimpleHTML`, `Zend_Dom_Query`, etc.?

Comment: $this->dom = @file_get_html($url); It is the definition of dom. It is not throwing error for all cases. Only few cases where it is not able to find the <img class="logo"> @nickb

Comment: from the @ in front of file_get_html I am guessing it is sometimes returning warnings or errors that you are ignoring instead of handling

Comment: Replace `@file_get_html()` with `file_get_html()` and handle errors instead of ignoring them.

Comment: So you are using [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), and what is happening is that it is failing to load your HTML file. It's not the case that the `<img>` tag isn't there. It is SimpleHTMLDOM failing to construct an object. Remove the `@` so you stop suppressing error messages on `file_get_html()`, that should help in showing you the problem.

Comment: @Anigel thx. that one worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that `$this->dom` is not an object, so you cannot use `$this->dom->find()`.

Comment: how to check if $this->dom is an object? I want to skip if $this->dom is not object.

Comment: Either use `instanceof` or check for `null` or `false` or similar.